# (3ds max SDK) How do I get the node of a Control?

Tags: 3dsmax, 3ds

I am implementing a LookAt Controller plugin by deriving from the Control class.

Everything works fine, except that I don't understand how I can get a INode pointer to the node that the Control belongs to. How do I get this pointer? (I need to access the pointer from within the code of my LookAt class.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get the node pointer.  Controls shouldn't know how their values are being used, just take your inputs, apply your algorithm to it, and return the value.

For example, to create a LookAt, I would define my Control to be of superclass type CTRL_ROTATION_CLASS_ID.  When this control evaluates (GetValue is called with method = CTRL_RELATIVE), it will be passed a pointer to the transform you want to apply your value to.  Assuming your rotation is part of a PRS, then the transform will be the parents transform, + the Position part of the (P)RS.

```
void YourClass::GetValue(TimeValue t, void* val, ...)
{
    Matrix3* pInTransform = reinterpret_cast<Matrix3*>(val);
    Point3& pMyPosition = pInTransform->GetTrans();
```

With the position, you can get the position of your target, then rotate/set that input matrix so your eye vector points at the target

I'd highly recommend the learning path section of the documentation for a general understanding of how the animation hierarchy in Max works.

http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-SDK-Programmer-Guide/files/GUID-A39314EC-15B4-4919-BB1B-318FFDC05DD8.htm

Comment: Ensure for method == CTRL_ABSOLUTE that you cast your val to the approriate type (eg for rotation, it will be a Quat, not a Matrix)

Comment: My problem is that one of my inputs to this specialized look-at algorithm is how the parent of the control's Node is oriented (that's why I wanted to get the Node, so I could access parent's transformation, etc.). As it seems now all I know about the control's node is its world transformation. If I could get the node's and its parent's world transformations, that would do.

Comment: Aha, okay. I checked now and it seems that the 'val' parameter is a Matrix3 than contains the PARENT's orientation and the node's position (as you said). It confused me a bit that they were mixed together in the same matrix instance. Actually I think that is all the inputs I need right now. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, isn't it a bit strange though that a Matrix3 can contain a translation part?